# MOSS 2007 Sort a dropdown content column globally

Tags: 2007, content-type, dropdown

I have a content type which requires all documents to be categorized by a dropdown box. Is there a way to sort the options that are displayed?

Comment: These should sort alphabetically automatically by the values entered. Is alpha listing not desired in this case and you want a different sorting order?

Comment: Correct, I want a different sorting order than the regular default alpha listing.